# Laravel eager loading Query issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have an issue in below query. The query returns result without running conditions inside eager function.
Although we have assigned values for $from_code and $to_code, it doesn't append those inner conditions. it just return all data within empperson table regardless the values assigned $from_code and $to_code .

```
$empPersons = Empperson::with(['empmaster' => function($query) use ($from_code,$to_code){
    if($from_code !=""){
         $query->where('empmaster.empCode','>=',$from_code);
    }
    if($to_code !=""){
         $query->where('empmaster.empCode','<=',$to_code);
    }
}]);
```

My Empmaster and Empperson models are as follows.

Empmaster.php

```
class Empmaster extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'empmaster';

    public function empPerson()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Empperson');
    }

}
```

Empperson.php

```
class Empperson extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'empperson';

    public function empMaster()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Empmaster','empmaster_id','id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as i understand it you want to condition the `Empperson` result with the relation exiting within those condition. Then you need to use `whereHas`, not `with`

```php
$empPersons = Empperson::whereHas('empmaster', function($query) use ($from_code,$to_code){
    if($from_code !=""){
         $query->where('empCode','>=',$from_code);
    }
    if($to_code !=""){
         $query->where('empCode','<=',$to_code);
    }
})->get();
```

`with` will only run the condition on the `empmaster` results. If you still need `empmaster` relation in the results, you can combine the two.

```php
$empPersons = Empperson::whereHas('empmaster', function($query) use ($from_code,$to_code){
    if($from_code !=""){
         $query->where('empCode','>=',$from_code);
    }
    if($to_code !=""){
         $query->where('empCode','<=',$to_code);
    }
})->with(['empmaster' => function($query) use ($from_code,$to_code){
    if($from_code !=""){
         $query->where('empCode','>=',$from_code);
    }
    if($to_code !=""){
         $query->where('empCode','<=',$to_code);
    }
}])->get();
```

So actually you can condition `Empperson` and also get all their `Empmaster` regardless of the condition.

Comment: empCode field is existing inside empmaster table.

Comment: @GayanFernando figured that, have you tried the answer ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just tested it now and it worked. Thank you so much for your advice.